# How to put some delay in calling an activity from another activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, gps

I have an application in which I'm receiving a sms containing his location.On receiving sms it calls another activity to start and passes that location to that activity to plot it on the map.Before calling the second activity it shows a toast like notification on the screen but somehoe due to calling second activity that toast doesn't come up.My question is how can we delay the calling of second activity from this activity ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {

                          Intent i=new Intent(SearxhJobs.this,JobsTypes.class);
                          startActivity(i);
                      }
                  }, 5000);
```

Here it waits upto 5 seconds to launch activity.

Hope it helps

Comment: Even better, now days, is to make the runnable a lambda.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with a `Handler` like this

```
    Handler h = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            Intent i = new Intent().setClass(ctx, MainActivity.class);                  
            startActivity(i);
        }           
    };

    h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1500); // 1500 is time in miliseconds
```

Answer (score 3):

Make an AsyncClass that does Thread.sleep() in the doInBackground() method, then navigate to your new activity in the your onPostExecute() method.

Call your toast message and then execute the AsyncClass.

Answer (score 3):

For Kotlin

```
 Handler().postDelayed({
            val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }, 5000)
```

Comment: to make it short `Handler().postDelayed({
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        }, 3000)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // if you are redirecting from a fragment then use getActivity() as the context.
          startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
          // To close the CurrentActitity, r.g. SpalshActivity
          finish();
       }
};

Handler h = new Handler();
// The Runnable will be executed after the given delay time
h.postDelayed(r, 1500); // will be delayed for 1.5 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the layout!

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            setContentView(R.layout.next); //where <next> is you target activity :)

            }
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: Bad solution. After 5 seconds, the activity may no longer exist, or it may be recreated. For example, due to a change in orientation.

Answer (score 0):

An example would be the following:

```
Handler TimeDelay=new Handler();
                if(previous=="geofence"){



                    tts.speak(previous,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null, null);
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            /*
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    MyBroadcastMessageReceiver.class.getName());
                            intent.putExtra("some additional data", choice);
                            someActivity.sendBroadcast(intent);*/
                            tts.speak(previous,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null, null);
                        }
                    };
                    TimeDelay.postDelayed(r, 150000);
```