# Give some delay after calling an Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, delay

I want to add some delay after calling an intent from a service. Ex: as shown below
How can i do it?

Any Help would be appreciated.

```
if (yAccel > 500 || yAccel < -500)
{
    gMeasure = true;
    lockStatus = 1; //lock done;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenLock.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    //delay for min 10 min
}
```

Comment: what you basically want? delay after SCreenLock.class is opened or delay for 10 min and then call ScreenLock.class?

Comment: check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965494/how-to-put-some-delay-in-calling-an-activity-from-another-activity

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with an Handler?

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenLock.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: To arthur_gg, The above method will send this intent (screenlock.class) after 1000 ms, is not it ? My requirement is opposite of it.. I want screenlock.class to be sent and then wait for 10 min .. How can i do it ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh ok I get it. You probably need to handle this in your ScreenLock activity.

Comment: To @arthur_gg ... Any suggestion, How can i do it? My requirement is Once, I send screenlock.class (screen gets locked), I want to wait for 2-3 min in same condition.