# How can I add a few seconds delay between activities in my app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, delay

I've been trying to add a few second delay to my activity swap in my basic app but whenever I try I get errors. I'm basing my attempts off of this previous thread ([How to put some delay in calling an activity from another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965494/how-to-put-some-delay-in-calling-an-activity-from-another-activity)) but have been unsuccessful multiple times. Can anyone help?

Here's my main activity code:

```
package winfield.joe.wind.v1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.BounceInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // public var
    private EditText text;

    // default function
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //localise this
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // (EditText) = typecast
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
    }

        //Will be executed by clicking on the calculate button because we assigned "calc" to the "onClick" Property
        public void calc(View view) {

                    bounce(view, 0.95f);           

            RadioButton toKilometers = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.toKilometers);
            RadioButton toKnots = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.toKnots);

            if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
                // if the text field is empty show the message "enter a valid number" via toast message
                //ATTENTION:localise this
                Toast.makeText(this, "enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                //int userInput = R.string.userInput;
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                //putExtra("userInput", userInput); 
                startActivity(i);

                // parse input Value from Text Field
                double inputValue = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
                // convert to...
                if (toKilometers.isChecked()) {
                    text.setText(String.valueOf(convertToKM(inputValue)));
                    // uncheck "to km" Button
                    toKilometers.setChecked(true);
                    // check "to knots" Button
                    toKnots.setChecked(false);
                } else { /* if toKnots button isChecked() */
                    text.setText(String.valueOf(convertToKnots(inputValue)));
                    // uncheck "to knots" Button
                    toKnots.setChecked(true);
                    // check "to km" Button
                    toKilometers.setChecked(false);
                }

            }

        }

    //bounce animation on button on-click
    public void bounce(View view, float amount) {
    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(amount, 1f, amount, 1f);
    anim.setDuration(750);
    anim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    view.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    private double convertToKM(double inputValue) {
        // convert knots to km
        return (inputValue * 1.8);
    }

    private double convertToKnots(double inputValue) {
        // convert km to knots
        return (inputValue * 0.539956803);
    }

}
```

Comment: At which point do you want to introduce the delay? Do you want to add the delay so that the animation is finished or is it somewhere else?

Comment: The animation only takes a second or so, i just wanted the delay to last say 5 seconds to give the user a chance to read the result (which appears onscreen from 'calc' ) and then go to the second activity. Everything atm works fine, just need to add a delay. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Ah ok. In that case handler.postDelayed() (answer below) is what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an Handler:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(...) {
                // start here the other Activity
            }

            else {

                // do something else

            }

        }
    }, YOUR_TIME_OUT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been looking at Handler but it causes an awful lot of errors when I try implementing it. I tried your way but I get about 5 errors which seems to be because of how my codes laid out. Is there another way would you know? Thanks.

Comment: can you show here the code you've used with Handler ?

Comment: Yes. I've tried the following from another thread (see this posts description) . 

`new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void calc() {
                      
                      //other code here

                      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); 
                      startActivity(i);
                    
                      //other code here

                      }
                  }, 5000);`

Comment: Actually, its what you've done above! sorry didn't spot that straight away. It leads to alot of errors though.

Comment: Actually in the above code posted by joewinfield91 There is no run method

Comment: you should remove the calc() method from the Handler body... it's useless... just call directly Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); startActivity(i);

Comment: yes @likithsai... it was changed the run() method with the calc() one

Comment: My errors consist of 12 similar errors like
:Syntax error on token ",", ; expected

Comment: @joewinfield91 the method inside the Handler should be run() and not calc()

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be that easy. I'm seeing an infinite loop of insert/delete }'s at the very end. My code isn't happy one bit with this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        @Override public void run() { 
            //other code here Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class); 
            startActivity(i); //other code here } }, 5000);
```