# Login screen isn't popping up

Tags: android, android-studio

So I have a problem where I made a GUI for login window in android studio.But when I try to start the app,it doesn't pop up.Also I have made a splashcreen which I want to pop up before login screen and it does.Also,I didnt do anything in the LoginActivitiy file which was created.I can't find the problem.Here is the manifest file.
Btw Im a beginner,go easy on me :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.projekat2021">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Projekat2021">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Its a little unclear. Do you want a popup above SplashActivity?

Comment: I want login screen to be shown after the SplashActivity.Splash screen is set to be shown for 3 seconds,and after those 3 seconds the mainActivity is shown.And i want to somehow insert the login screen in between those two.

Comment: First you need to go from SplashActitivy to LoginAcitivy [using a handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965494/how-to-put-some-delay-in-calling-an-activity-from-another-activity) and i guess after you "log in" you start the MainActivity as a simple intent

Comment: @javdromero That did the trick,thank you very much!